# combine string in python pandas

Tags: arrays, string, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I got a problem when analyzing dataset about combining string together.
The data frame looks like the one below:

```
IP      Event
01      check
01      redo
01      view
02      check
02      check
03      review
04      delete
```

As you can see, the IP contains duplicates. My question is, how can I get the results of combining the Event group by each IP in order.For example, the result I'm looking for is:

```
IP    result
01    check->redo->view
02    check->check
03    review
04    delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
In [27]: df.groupby('IP').agg('->'.join).reset_index()
Out[27]:
   IP              Event
0  01  check->redo->view
1  02       check->check
2  03             review
3  04             delete
```

or

```
In [26]: df.groupby('IP').agg('->'.join)
Out[26]:
                Event
IP
01  check->redo->view
02       check->check
03             review
04             delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with lambda:

```
df.groupby("IP")['Event'].apply(lambda x: '->'.join(x)).reset_index()


  #  IP           Event
# 0   1  check->redo->view
# 1   2       check->check
# 2   3             review
# 3   4             delete
```